# Swing: how do you drag multiple rows from a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

I have a JTable. If my selection mode is [`ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_SELECTION), I can drag data from the table elsewhere and it works fine.

But if my selection mode is [`ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#SINGLE_SELECTION), when I go to drag the data, it resets the selection to a single selection.

How can I drag multiple rows from a JTable?

Comment: hmm ... can't reproduce: if I click into an already selected row, all selections are kept and dragged

Comment: OK, I'll whittle down to a simple example I can post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT***

Drag and drop of multiple rows should work by default, with or without setting the selection mode. With the caveat that drag is enabled on your JTable.

Comment: don't think any twiddling is needed - see the BasicDnD example in snoracle's swing tutorial: works-fine-for-me

Comment: @kleopatra - confirmed, dragging multiple rows works for me as well.

Comment: Aha, I hadn't set the setDragEnabled() on my JTable.